# Salt Before Hash or Hash Before Salt?

Tags: hash, passwords, salt

It is clear that we should salt and hash passwords before writing to the database. For this purpose, I have seen 2 different fundamental approaches:

1. Salting before hashing

   ```
   hash(password + salt)
   ```
2. Hashing before salting

   ```
   hash(hash(password) + salt)
   ```

My instincts somehow say that there is something wrong in the 2nd approach due to the hashing before salting, but that is only my instinct without cryptography basis.

Is one of these methods is more secure than the other? Is there any weakness in the 2nd method?

Comment: Your two examples aren't really equivalent, and `hash(password) + salt` is self-evidently pointless!

Comment: This is what [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) is for but does it securely. But these days you should be using a password directed method such as `PBKDF2` or `crypt`; if you care about security. The derivation (hashing) needs to be secure (MD5 isn't), salted and slow (to make attempts costly.

Answer (score 1):

Recommended hash algorithms like PBKDF2 or BCrypt cannot calculate a hash in a single pass, so neither of the described approaches is sufficient. They should offer a cost factor, which controls the necessary time to calculate a single hash. The cost factor determines how many rounds of hashing are done.

**How the salt is applied is part of the algorithm**, so it is best to leave this to the algorithm.

This is how BCrypt applies the salt (from Wikipedia):

```
EksBlowfishSetup(cost, salt, key)
    state \gets InitState()
    state \gets ExpandKey(state, salt, key)
    repeat (2cost)
        state \gets ExpandKey(state, 0, key)
        state \gets ExpandKey(state, 0, salt)
    return state
```